# Hebrew Calendar in Google Spreadsheets?

Tags: google-sheets, calendar

Does Google Spreadsheets support the Hebrew Calendar in any way?

If not, are there any workarounds for representing dates in this format?

Comment: in Excel there's a macro or function =DateToHeb which converts Gregorian dates to Hebrew Calendar dates. I have yet to find an equivalent in GoogleSheets though :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One manual way to achieve that is by adding a hidden column that contains the Gregorian date (converted manually).
Obviously not an efficient way, but does the job.